# parsing array contents and adding the values

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have several files that end in ".log". Last but three lines contain the data of interest.

Example File contents (Last four lines. fourth line is blank):

Total: 150

Success: 120

Error: 30

I am reading these contents into an array and trying to find an elegant way to:
1)extract the numeric data for each category (Total, Success, Error). Error out if numeric data is not there in the second part
2)Add them all up

I came up with the following code (getLastXLines function excluded for brevity) that returns the aggregate:

```
def getSummaryData(testLogFolder):
    (path, dirs, files) = os.walk(testLogFolder).next()
    #aggregate = [grandTotal, successTotal, errorTotal]
    aggregate = [0, 0, 0]
    for currentFile in files:
            fullNameFile = path + "\\" + currentFile
            if currentFile.endswith(".log"):
                with open(fullNameFile,"r") as fH:
                    linesOfInterest=getLastXLines(fH, 4)
                #If the file doesn't contain expected number of lines
                if len(linesOfInterest) != 4:
                    print fullNameFile + " doesn't contain the expected summary data"
                else:
                    for count, line in enumerate(linesOfInterest[0:-1]):
                        results = line.split(': ')
                        if len(results)==2:
                            aggregate[count] += int(results[1])
                        else:
                            print "error with " + fullNameFile + " data. Not adding the total"

    return aggregate
```

Being relatively new to python, and seeing the power of it, I feel there may be a more powerful and efficient way to do this. May be there is a short list comprehension to do this kind of stuff? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getSummaryData(testLogFolder):
    summary = {'Total':0, 'Success':0, 'Error':0}
    (path, dirs, files) = os.walk(testLogFolder).next()
    for currentFile in files:
            fullNameFile = path + "\\" + currentFile
            if currentFile.endswith(".log"):
                with open(fullNameFile,"r") as fH:
                    for pair in [line.split(':') for line in fH.read().split('\n')[-5:-2]]:
                        try:
                            summary[pair[0].strip()] += int(pair[1].strip())
                        except ValueError:
                            print pair[1] + ' is not a number'
                        except KeyError:
                            print pair[0] + ' is not "Total", "Success", or "Error"'
    return summary
```

Piece by peice:

```
fH.read().split('\n')[-5:-2]
```

Here we take the last 4 lines except the very last of the file

```
line.split(':') for line in
```

From those lines, we break by the colon

```
try:
    summary[pair[0].strip()] += int(pair[1].strip())
```

Now we try to get a number from the second, and a key from the first and add to our total

```
except ValueError:
    print pair[1] + ' is not a number'
except KeyError:
    print pair[0] + ' is not "Total", "Success", or "Error"'
```

And if we find something that isn't a number, or a key that isn't what we are looking for, we print an error

Comment: thank you. I like the exception handling part, it's really good. I prefer not to read the whole file so I still like to use my getLastXLines code. I will give you an up vote and wait for any better answers :)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how are you reading only the last lines? Last i checked, files don't work that way, unless you're using some obscure OS that uses per-file records.

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html Specifically file.seek and file.tell will let you read specific bytes in any order